# Nginx Error 500 instead 400 only for a specific website

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx server that only one specific wordpress website is getting error 500 instead 404 for non existing pages. All the other ones are working properly. How can I fix it? Thanks!

This is my default:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Curl result:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 09 Apr 2017 21:23:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d7a99a0f37ef37e26401ed3f8e4c16b8c1491772998; expires=Mon, 0                                                                                        9-Apr-18 21:23:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.consertae.com.br; HttpOnly
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 34d086d8407518a0-EWR

<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Error log to a non existing page called /test:

```
2017/04/09 18:23:19 [error] 10655#0: *7585 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/error/404.html", 
client: IP-ADDRESS, server: mywebsiteaddress.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web8.sock", 
host: "mywebsiteaddress.com"
```

3 last error log (nginx):

```
    2017/04/09 13:19:45 [error] 10655#0: *3026 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions" while reading response header from upstream, client: 179.34.116.60, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/js/whitelist.php?lang=pt&db=c0db_Consertae_prod&token=3bfd3b6b229d7c7751c4247b59279f46 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock:", host: "159.203.183.176:8081"


2017/04/09 13:19:45 [error] 10655#0: *3049 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions" while reading response header from upstream, client: 179.34.116.60, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?lang=pt&db=c0db_Consertae_prod&token=3bfd3b6b229d7c7751c4247b59279f46 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock:", host: "159.203.183.176:8081"

2017/04/09 13:19:46 [error] 10655#0: *3049 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions" while reading response header from upstream, client: 179.34.116.60, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1&token=3bfd3b6b229d7c7751c4247b59279f46&aPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.YzBkYl9Db25zZXJ0YWVfcHJvZA%3D%3D&vPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.YzBkYg%3D%3D.Q29uc2VydGFlX3Byb2Q%3D&pos=0&pos2_name=&pos2_value=&searchClause=&searchClause2=&_nocache=1491754786547145505 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock:", host: "159.203.183.176:8081"
```

PHP-FPM error log:

```
    [02-Apr-2017 06:25:05] NOTICE: error log file re-opened
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:02] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:02] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:03] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 02:24:06] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:04] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:04] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:05] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 18:55:08] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:02] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:02] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:03] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:07] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:07] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 19:02:08] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:03] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:03] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:04] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Apr-2017 20:40:07] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] WARNING: [pool web6] child 22265 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 29712.198946 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] NOTICE: [pool web6] child 9765 started
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] WARNING: [pool web6] child 21659 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 49374.658113 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] NOTICE: [pool web6] child 9766 started
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] WARNING: [pool web6] child 22379 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 29604.083741 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] NOTICE: [pool web6] child 9768 started
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] WARNING: [pool web6] child 21660 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 49374.661785 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:02] NOTICE: [pool web6] child 9769 started
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:03] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:03] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web6.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Apr-2017 10:23:04] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:02] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Apr-2017 10:24:07] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/sbin/php5-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=9, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=10, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=11, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=12, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web3.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=13, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=14, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=15, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=17, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web7.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web8.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=16, "/var/lib/php5-fpm/web8.sock"
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 871
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Apr-2017 10:39:03] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[09-Apr-2017 10:52:01] WARNING: [pool web1] child 10633 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 778.112914 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:52:01] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 11235 started
[09-Apr-2017 10:52:01] WARNING: [pool web1] child 10632 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 778.121118 seconds from start
[09-Apr-2017 10:52:01] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 11237 started
```

Updated:
Just fix it. The problem was the folder /web/error was empty, and that folder must contain the error pages. So I copied a file 404.html from another installation and now everything is working. Pages that do not exist are getting 404 error code.

The log file where I found the solution was in the following path \log\error.log.

Comment: Please demonstrate the problem. Suggest you edit your post to include a "curl -i" (showing response headers) of a page request. I'm mostly interested in the response headers and a couple of lines of body that show it's a "not found". Also please showing the matching access log entry and if one exists the error log entry. If there's a matching PHP error log include that too.

Comment: @Tim just added the information you need in the post

Comment: Please add the Nginx access log that corresponds to that curl. The internal server error is coming from PHP. Please find the logs, could be under PHP or PHP-FPM on your file system. On my server the logs are in /var/log/php-fpm/5.6/error.log

Comment: @Tim I could find Nginx error log in /var/log/nginx/error.log 
the access log is in the same path /access.log, but I could not find any request to the /test url.

Comment: You've given the Nginx error log. If a response was sent to the client it will be in the access log. It's not critical. However when I asked for PHP logs you seem to have found some kind of Nginx/PHP log which has phpmyadmin errors, which don't seem relevent. You need to find the php-fpm log and entries corresponding to your request, they're the key to solve this problem.

Comment: @Tim just found it! It is in /var/log/php5-fpm.log. Just updated the post, please check.

Comment: There are no errors in there. Your logs have completely different times, though this could be time zone. To solve the problem you need to be able to **trace a single request through your stack**, not just give random logs. ***Please*** do your curl -i again and update all logs above so they correspond to the curl you made and the error generated. If you can't provide appropriate information to help people answer your question it will be closed and you'll have to hire a consultant to help.

Comment: My current setup is Linux Debian 8 (Jessie), ISPConfig 3, NginX, PHP5 with FastCGI, and MySQL. Can you guide me in this proccess? What I did wrong? I''m a beginner, sorry.

Comment: Sorry but if you can't follow a transaction through logs you're going to have to pay a consultant to help you.

Comment: Just found the solution! Missing html files in the folder /web/error/

Comment: Great :) Perhaps you could provide an answer, including perhaps your problem solving steps, so others could learn from this and solve the problem if it comes up for them.

Comment: Well welcome :) This was a tricky problem, and a lot of information was needed to solve it. We can often answer questions. Perhaps in your answer you could provide a bit more detail about how you found the problem - for example you've given a relative path to the logs, was that the Nginx, PHP, or another log file that led you to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just fix it. The problem was the folder /web/error was empty, and that folder must contain the error pages. So I copied a file 404.html from another installation and now everything is working. Pages that do not exist are getting 404 error code.

The log file where I found the solution was in the following path \log\error.log. It was indicating error trying to get files from web/error.